# Regex: 3 words with 2 dashes in between

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm looking for regex that matches this pattern:

```
/word-word-word/ MATCH  
/word-word/ DO NOT MATCH  
/word/ DO NOT MATCH
```

Starts with /, 3 words in a row, with 2 dashes in between, ends with /

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
\/^[A-Za-z]+([-][A-Za-z]+)+([-][A-Za-z]+)$\/
```

Comment: How is it now working ? Have you tried it on some inputs ?

Comment: Paste your regexp into regex101.com and then read the description it gives you real carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Starts with /, 3 words in a row, with 2 dashes in between, ends with /

But you are using `\/^[A-Za-z]+([-][A-Za-z]+)+([-][A-Za-z]+)$\/`

Which means start of string should be word but there should be a `/` before it. **It's a paradox.**

Those slashes should come inside anchors. Also you don't need `[ ]` for `-` since it's a single character.

**Regex:** `^\/[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\/$`

Comment: Why do you need to escape forward slashes?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Not to confuse with `/`  as delimiter.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! Works just fine.